# Navigation from tabbedPage, clear stack in .Net maui

Tags: maui, prism

Problem is related to navigation from TabbedPage.

When we crate tabbed page and navigate deeply from one tab into e.g. details, Prism will open Page as new(no into content of tabbed page) and will clear stack and we canon't go back to tabbed page. According to my check, prim will clear backstack.

Github: https://github.com/michal-ziolkowski-dev/maui_tabbed_page_navigation

Steps to Reproduce
Run app
Go to TabbedPage
Go to Details Page
Page should be open into content of tab page and back button should be visible

Affected platforms
iOS, Android

I try use native maui navigation and it works, so problem is on PRism side, or i call sth., wrong.